# Failed to create provisioning profile in XCODE with IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run xcode project in simulator. I create xcode project using Ionic command:

```
ionic cordova run ios --device
```

When I click "run" in XCode project editor, then build is failed. The error is:

> Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered
>   in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device
>   to have Xcode register it.

I use IOS simulator. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run ionic project in ios simulator you have to run `ionic emulate iOS` command. when you want to run ionic project in ios device at that time run `ionic run ios --device` command.